# como evitar que pgadmin III se desconecte de postgresql cada 15 minutos aproximadamente?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

lo que sucede es que me alejo del escritorio unos minutos y cuando quiero retomar o usar nuevamente el pgadmin III para acceder a mi base de datos postgresql, me salta un mensaje de error diciendo que la conexion se ha perdido y tengo que cerrrar el pgadmin y volver a abrirlo. Hay alguna solucion para este problema?

Comment: que version de postgresql y sistema operativo tienes?

Comment: postgresql 10 instalado en ubuntu 16.04 / cliente windows 10 pgadmin 4

Comment: Pusiste en tu pregunta que pdadmin3 es el que se desconecta

Comment: igualmente me ha pasado lo mismo con pgadmin 3 y windows 7. en varios foros he notado que a varios usuarios les ocurre lo mismo, pero no he encontrado respuesta satisfactoria en ningun sitio

Comment: realmente no se si es un comportamiento del pgadmin o de postgresql

Comment: para postgres 10 debes utilizar pgadmin4, el 3 tiene problemas de compatibilidad y me parece que ya no es soportado. Puedes probar con otro cliente que no sea pgadmin. Prueba SQuirreL

Comment: para postgresql 10 uso pgadmin 4. el ejemplo que puse de pgadmin 3 sobre windows 7 era para la version 9 y anteriores